# Urban Airship not updating tags on iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I am trying to update the tags on my iOS device. The code looks like

```
NSArray* tags = @[@"some-tag", @"some-other-tag"]; // Tags are actually 55 characters long
UAPush* push = [UAPush shared];
[push setTags:tags];//update locally
[push updateRegistration];//update server
NSLog(@"Updated tags %@", push.tags);
```

The push.tags prints correctly. However on the UA Audience page I can see that the tags have not been updated.
To make things even stranger the API call `https://go.urbanairship.com/api/device_tokens/{{token}}` returns different tags then what is on my device and shown in UA Audience page.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I see the exact problem... what's going on with UA??

Comment: I've experienced the UA "Audience" -> "Device Tokens" page showing NO tags, but calling the API call you mentioned above shows them correctly.  I think they're getting registered but there is some sort of error in their UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urban Airship was experiencing a delay in registration events for specific apps related to the significant influx of new device tokens.  The additional device tokens are created by iOS 7 as part of the new one device token per production app configuration.

Registration delays should be cleared as of the time of this post.